# daprd container ready status is showing as false and deployment getting failed with Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes, minikube, dapr

I have developed the grpc api using the .NET 7 with dapr and I'm trying deploy the api in the minikube kubernets cluster in my local, all working till the time I have set to `dapr.io/sidecar-liveness-probe-delay-seconds`,after this time delay deployment is getting failed with `Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500` and still daprd status is showing as false. below is the my deployment yaml file and the dapr config file, I don't know what I'm missing and what is the wrong. I tried multiple solution didn't work, if some one can help to fix this issue will be much appricaited.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: authservice
  labels:
     app: authservice
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: authservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: authservice
  annotations:
    dapr.io/enabled: "true"
    dapr.io/app-id: "authservice"
    dapr.io/app-port: "8087"
    dapr.io/app-protocol: "grpc"
    dapr.io/enable-api-logging: "true"
    dapr.io/enable-app-health-check: "true"
    dapr.io/sidecar-liveness-probe-delay-seconds: "2000"
    dapr.io/sidecar-readiness-probe-delay-seconds: "3000"
    dapr.io/log-level: "debug"
    dapr.io/app-health-check-path: "/v1.0/heathz"
    dapr.io/config: "loginappconfig"
spec:
  containers:
  - name: login
    image: shakirisa/authservice:8
    # env:
    # - name: APP_PORT
    #   value: "3000"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8087
    imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Below is my dapr config file.

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
   name: loginappconfig
namespace: dapr-system
spec:
   tracing:
   samplingRate: "1"
   zipkin:
      endpointAddress: "http://zipkin.dapr-system:9411/api/v2/spans"
```

Command that I used to install the dapr in the kubernet cluster(minikube)

```
dapr init -k
```

Below is log of the daprd container in dapr dashboard.

[image]

Below is the kubernets application pod's dashboard.

[image]